# Rails Devise Conditional authentication_keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

Is there any way of making the authentication_keys configuration conditional depending on the user type?

For instance in my User model I have two different user, standard user and student, defined by the value of a bitmask attribute. I want to authenticate Students on the basis of username and school_id. Standard users don't have to have a value for school_id. In order to accommodate this I have two types of login screens, one for students and another for standard users. The student login screen has a hidden school_id field that authenticates them to their school.

In my devise configuration file I have:

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :username, :school_id ]
```

However with this setup standard users are unable to login, my guess is that it's expecting a school_id for all Users being authenticated. Is it possible to make the authentication keys conditional? Or give an allow_blank option for school_id? I want to be able to keep standard users and students in the same model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simply do in your models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, authentication_keys: [:username]
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, authentication_keys: [:username, :student_id]
end
```

Comment: Hey José - is it necessary to place them both inside of different models? Right now they're both considered Users and are distinguished through cancan authorization.

Comment: Yes, they'd need to be different models.

Comment: I'm using devise 3.2.2 but the answer does not work for me :-(
In my app I have a:
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:email]
end

Comment: I want to make authentication_keys conditional in single model. Eg:Don't make email compulsory for certain conditions, is this possible ?